# How to express that $y$ is a natural number and $x$ is an odd natural number in a compact language?

Tags: notation, terminology

I have this expression
$ \frac {x^2}{y}$ for all $y\in\mathbb{N}$ and only odd values of $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it possible to express these assumptions (especially that $x$ is odd) in a compact mathematical language?

> I mean if I want to use this sentence
> " $ \frac {x^2}{y}$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ ",
> what should I add to this sentence to express that $x$ is odd?

Comment: $\{x: \exists n \in \mathbb N, x=2n+1 \}$ if you have $0 \in \mathbb N$, changing $+$ to $-$ if you have $0 \not\in \mathbb N$

Comment: Updated my answer, please check if that's what you want

Comment: You could also write $2\nmid x$, which is short for "$2$ does not divide $x$". This is very short, but maybe harder to read. By the way, there is nothing wrong with writing "where $x$ is odd" or something alike, that is probably the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is odd implies that $x = 2n+1$ for $n \in \Bbb N$

$x=2n-1$ also works

Why that? because odd numbers are one less or one more than the even numbers and even numbers are of the form $x = 2n$

You should add "$(x,y)\in \Bbb N\space \text{and}\space x = 2n+1\space \text{for some}\space n\in \Bbb N$" to your solution/statement

Comment: "for $n\in\mathbb N$" and "$\forall n\in\mathbb N$ are both incorrect. $x$ does not equal every odd number. Instead, $x=2n+1$ for *some* $n\in\mathbb N$ (if $0\in \mathbb N$). That's the quantifier $\exists$, not $\forall$.

Comment: Thanks, edited it

Comment: This may not be a universal opinion, but I would still say that "for $n\in\mathbb N$" should not be written where one means "for some $n\in\mathbb N$", since I think it most often is used to mean "for all $n\in\mathbb N$".

Answer (score 1):

Since $y$ is in your denominator, I assume you take $0\notin\mathbb N$. If that's the case, then every odd natural $x$ can be written as $2k-1$ for some natural $k$. If you don't need to reference $x$ later, you could skip straight to $k$ and write things like

> Consider $(2k-1)^2/y$ for some $y,k\in\mathbb N$.

or

> For all $y,k\in \mathbb N$, note that $(2k-1)^2/y$ blah blah...

If you *do* need to reference $x$, you could write something like

> Let $x,y\in \mathbb N$ with $x$ odd, then $x^2/y$ blah blah...

Comment: If the downvoter would like to provide criticism either publicly or privately (via the email linked in my profile), it would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks, the last option works for me :)

Comment: @MarkS. Please don't think that I downvoted your answer.